# Blazor .Net 6.0 Hot Reload

Tags: blazor, hot-reload, .net-6.0

I have an asp.net hosted blazor wasm app that I just upgraded from 5.0 to 6.0.  When trying hot reload either from VS 2022 or from dotnet watch run I get the following error in the browser console:

aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:138

```
   Error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.HotReload.WebAssemblyHotReload.ApplyHotReloadDelta(String moduleIdString, Byte[] metadataDelta, Byte[] ilDeta)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.InvokeSynchronously(JSRuntime jsRuntime, DotNetInvocationInfo& callInfo, IDotNetObjectReference objectReference, String argsJson)
at Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.DotNetDispatcher.Invoke(JSRuntime jsRuntime, DotNetInvocationInfo& invocationInfo, String argsJson)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Services.DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime.InvokeDotNet(String assemblyName, String methodIdentifier, String dotNetObjectId, String argsJson)
at Object._convert_exception_for_method_call (https://localhost:44362/_framework/dotnet.6.0.0.qme34vl4fz.js:1:178709)
at Object._handle_exception_for_call (https://localhost:44362/_framework/dotnet.6.0.0.qme34vl4fz.js:1:180678)
at managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_InvokeDotNet (https://mono-wasm.invalid/managed__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Components_WebAssembly_Services_DefaultWebAssemblyJSRuntime_InvokeDotNet:20:21)
at Object.invokeDotNetFromJS (https://localhost:44362/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js?version=32330328618b4ff08635274a6f31248c:1:42078)
at g (https://localhost:44362/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js?version=32330328618b4ff08635274a6f31248c:1:1618)
at Object.e.invokeMethod (https://localhost:44362/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js?version=32330328618b4ff08635274a6f31248c:1:2665)
at Object.St.Te._internal.applyHotReload (https://localhost:44362/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js?version=32330328618b4ff08635274a6f31248c:1:56100)
at https://localhost:44362/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:136:33
at Array.forEach ()
at applyBlazorDeltas (https://localhost:44362/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:134:12)

Answer (score 5):

I had to put `UseStaticFiltes()` AFTER `UseBlazorFrameworkFiles()`, otherwise the NullReferenceException occurs. This works for me:

```
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same issue, and ran across your post while trying to troubleshoot.

Much to my chagrin, I admit that the reason is due to running the Release build. I must have (somehow) changed it to the Release build at some point without realizing.

Once back on the Debug build (but without the debugger attached), Hot Reload is now working again.

Error in Visual Studio:

[image: Error in Visual Studio]

Error in Chrome:

[image: Error in Chrome]

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix the error for me.  I was already running in debug configuration.  I tried switching to release then back to debug just to see if it would make a difference- it didn't

Comment: Blazor wasm does NOT support hot reload.

Comment: @Greg that is not true.  As of Visual Studio 2022/.NET6, Blazor WASM does support hot reload as long as you are running without debugging.  It does seem to be a bit buggy, but has still saved our dev team some time.

Comment: It is true - tested extensively on a number of platforms, all tested on vanilla blazor projects - in Blazor wasm projects, css updates DO NOT trigger hot reload - Inner HTML changes DO NOT trigger hot reload - tested on VS CODE and VS 2022 - ran from terminal and tried from power shell 7.2.1 ( downloaded today ). The file change IS recognised according to the logs, but after that nothing happens - No UI updates - just freezes.

Comment: And Sayed Hashimi from Microsoft says its not working for him on release 17.0.3. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/blazor-hot-reload-not-working/1480369

Comment: Please see this video I just created showing the Hot Reload in action.  I start a new Blazor WASM project from scratch.  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pro48zPsTZk)

Answer (score 1):

Check inside your `*.csproj` project file to see if there is any configuration related to the target platform. If so, delete it and try again. For example:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have resolved this issue by updating all **Microsoft** packages to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was fixed by changing `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` from `Local` to `Development`.  More details here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39269